# properly chunking these sentences

Tags: regex, nltk, text-chunking

Here are two similar sentences:

"Students who receive favourable letters achieve this by getting good grades due to high intelligence and good ethics."

"Students who receive favourable letters do so by getting good grades due to high intelligence and good ethics."

I am chunking them and I have a good parse so far as follows:

[parse tree of sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh30O.png)

I want to parse the parts "do so by getting" and "achieve this by getting"

As you can see they are not working.  Here is the parse I have:

```
               E: {<DT*>?(<NN.*>+)}
               QUALIFIED_COL: {<DT>?<JJ><COL_NAME>}
               PRODUCT_COL: {(<COL_NAME>|<QUALIFIED_COL>)((<CC>(<COL_NAME>|<QUALIFIED_COL>))+)} 
               RELATION: {<WP*>?<WDT*>?<RB*>?<V.*>}
                         {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN.*>+}
                         {<JJ*>?<TO*>}
                         {<VBP>((<RB>|<DT>)+)<IN><VBG>}
               TARGET_COL_NAME: {<NN.*>}"""
```

So, you can see that this

```
{<VBP>((<RB>|<DT>)+)<IN><VBG>}
```

does not work.  Can anyone help?

Edit

tried

```
{<VBP>(<RB>|<DT>)<IN><VBG>}
```

And it still fails to capture this text as a "Relation"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUaJ3.png)

Comment: Did you try `{<VBP>(<RB>|<DT>)<IN><VBG>}` ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, it failed to capture the full relation.  See my edit.